# How do i parse a XML with the type defined as XSD:any

Tags: java, xml

I have a XML structure which has the content type defined as xs:any in the schema. At runtime the schema corresponding to the structure that is being passed in the XML would also be sent. Is there a way that i can parse this xs:any node with the schema that i get as part of the input

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the schema at compile time you will have to deal with a generic model to interact with the data from the xs:any part.
[This](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic) may be what you are looking for.